# Can installutil 4.0 be used to install a service written with a older version of the .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

Can the installutil exe in folder 4.0 be used to install a service written with a older version 2.0 of the .NET Framework?

As folder 2.0 doesn't contain installutil exe. Do I need to install .net framework 2.0 to install those services built using framework 2.0?

Comment: I don't know for certain but I can't see why not. What happened when you tried it? :)

Comment: i am able to install these services using installutil in 4.0 folder but unable to start services as those are referencing .net framework 2.0 assemblies which are not available on my machine.

Comment: Hi, have you solved this issue?